# jQuery .data doesn't work with .change()

Tags: jquery, html

I have a form select with some options. The options have the atribute "data-image". When i try to catch the data value on .change of select, the return send me "undefined".

**HTML**

```
<select id="onde">
  <option value="1000" data-image="SP">Sampa</option>
  <option value="2000" data-image="RJ">Rio</option>
</select>
```

**jQuery**

```
$("#onde").change(function(){
    var value = $(this).data("image");
    alert(value);
});
```

The alert return "undefined". When I change the `.data()` for `.val()`, returns the value of the option (1000 or 2000), and why don't return the data-image with data?

Comment: The `data-image` attribute is not on the `<select>`. It's on the `<option>`...

Answer (score 2):

You need to find the selected option

```
var value = $(this).find('option:selected').data("image");
```

In the change handler `this` refers to the `select` element which does not have the `data-image` attribute, so you need to find the selected(using [:selected selector](http://api.jquery.com/selected-selector/)) option first then its data value

Answer (score 0):

Works fine..

JS:

```
$("#onde").change(function(){
    var value = $(this[this.selectedIndex]).data("image");
    alert(value);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can do this way:

```
$('select').on('change', function(){

  var value = $('#onde :selected').data("image");

    alert(value);    
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsbin.com/zequjuna/1/edit)